# How to extract a sub-url from a URL using regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext3, build-system

I'm trying to make a PHP build system in Sublime-text to run PHP script in browser from the editor.

This is the build system I'm using to run PHP script from sublime-text. `Run`is working great as long as I have file in the root `/var/www/html` directory.
But if the file is in a subdirectory this build fails.
i.e `/var/www/html/SubDirectory`.

I build another variant **Run(SUB)** using regex for running files which are in sub-directory But it fails if i have file in more than one subdirectory. i.e `/var/www/html/SubDirectory1/SubDirectory2`
Suppose the url is `/var/www/html/Library/opac/index.php` When I run it in the browser it shows `localhost/opac/index.php`.

```
{
"cmd": ["php", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
"selector": "embedding.php",
"variants": 
[
    {
        "shell_cmd": "gnome-terminal -- bash -c \"php $file;echo;echo Press enter to exit...;read\"", 
        "name": "Run(terminal)"
    },
    {
        "cmd":["firefox","localhost/$file_name"],
        "name":"Run"
    },
            {
        "cmd":["firefox","localhost/${file_path/.*[\\\/]//}/$file_name"],
        "name":"Run(SUB)"
    },


]
```

}

I want a regex pattern which extract sub-url after the html/.
How to always extract sub-url after html so the url become  `localhost/Library/opac/index.php`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @splash58 I want to extract url in build system of sublime-text not in a php script.

Comment: `/var/www/html/Library/opac/index.php => localhost/opac/index.php` ? why do you say about 'html'  - its after `Library/` ?

Comment: @splash58 I said about html directory not html extension files ..